# pdo query alter table where column name not existing?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
 <?php
   $month=$_SESSION['month'];
    $colname=$_SESSION['colname'];
require('connect.php');
global $pdo;
 $stmt=$pdo->prepare('SHOW COLUMNS FROM `selections` LIKE ":s%"');
$stmt=bindParam(':s',$colname);$stmt->execute();$row =$stmt->fetch()?true:false;
if($row==false){$sql=$pdo->prepare("ALTER TABLE  `$month` ADD  `$colname` VARCHAR( 120)NOT NULL DEFAULT 'absent'");
$sql->execute();}else{die("error".print_r($sql>errorinfo()));
}
 ?>
```

code error Call to undefined function bindParam();
bindparm error 
here  $month is month select dynamically by user and $colname is also select by user

```
<?php
$month=$_SESSION['month'];
$colname=$_SESSION['colname'];
$tot='present';
require('connect.php');
  global $pdo;
$stmt=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE `$month` SET `$colname`=:a WHERE roll =:foo");
 $stmt=bindparam(':a',$tot);
  foreach( $value as $value)
           {
      $stmt>bindParam(':foo',$value);
       $stmt->execute();
          }
    if($stmt==false)
   {    
     die("error".print_r($stmt->errorinfo()));
      } ?>
```

Comment: Please format the code

Comment: @user3144122 , why do you revert the formatting edit ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**try this:**

```
session_start();
$month=$_SESSION['month'];
$colname=$_SESSION['colname'];
require('connect.php');
global $pdo;
$stmt=$pdo->prepare('SHOW COLUMNS FROM `selections` LIKE :s');
$query->bindValue(":s", $stmt);
$stmt->execute();
$row =$stmt->fetch()?true:false;
if($row==false){
  $sql=$pdo->prepare("ALTER TABLE  `$month` ADD  `$colname` VARCHAR( 120 )NOT NULL DEFAULT 'absent'");
  $sql->execute();
}else{
  die("error".print_r($sql>errorinfo()));
}
```

**For second ERROR:**

```
$month=$_SESSION['month'];
$colname=$_SESSION['colname'];
$tot='present';
require('connect.php');
global $pdo;
$stmt=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE `$month` SET `$colname`=:a WHERE roll =:foo");
$stmt=bindparam(':a',$tot);
 //I don't know what are in the $value
foreach( $value as $v){
    $stmt->bindParam(':foo',$v);
    if( !$stmt->execute())
    {
        die("error".print_r($stmt->errorinfo()));
    }
}
```

Comment: sir my second code not work properly where data insert into data base

Comment: @user3144122 : First try it. If not worked then tell me  the output of var_dump($value);

Comment: thank you sir its  working thank you for your kind help for your valuable time....

Comment: @user3144122 : If it worked please Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.It will be a green mark if it is accepted correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**Error 1**

You probably mean :

```
$stmt->bindParam(':s',$colname);
```

**Error 2**

Also, you haven't started your session by `session_start()`

**Error 3**

It should be:

```
die("error".print_r($sql->errorinfo(), true));
```

**Error 4**

You may want:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':foo',$value);
```

instead of:

```
$stmt>bindParam(':foo',$value);
```

by the way, you prefer to write codes in single line?